# How to convert date in YYYYMMDD format (int) to datetime format in hive?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive, hiveql

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190901','yyyymmdd'));
OK
+----------------------+
|         _c0          |
+----------------------+
| 2019-01-01 00:09:00  |
+----------------------+
```

Desired output is 2019-09-01 00:00:00 . What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure how to format display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. mm is minutes and MM is month.

It should be yyyyMMdd instead of yyyymmdd

Answer (score 2):

Efficient method is to use substr and concat_ws:

```
 with your_table as (select 20190901 as initial_date)
   select concat_ws('-',substr(initial_date, 1, 4),  substr(initial_date, 5, 2), substr(initial_date, 7, 2)) as dt from your_table;
```

Result

```
2019-09-01
```

Or using regexp_replace:

```
   select regexp_replace(initial_date, '^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3')
```

If you prefer using unix_timestamp, then use proper format `'yyyyMMdd'`:

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190901','yyyyMMdd'));
```

See data formats here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)